# Prevent Amazon Echo from starting in the middle of program flow

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

I made a quiz skill where a user is first prompted with a response from Alexa asking if they are ready to proceed. From there, the user must either say yes or no to activate a corresponding `AMAZON.YesIntent` or `AMAZON.NoIntent` respectively. The quiz then begins, and a user says an answer letter followed by the answer for each question. I use a server to simulate state within my skill.

Normally I start my skill by saying:

> "Alexa, start Quiz Skill"

But, I am finding that simulating state using a server does not make a very robust voice interface for the Echo. If a user says:

> "Alexa, ask Quiz Skill yes"

The skill will jump to whatever I have setup to trigger when Amazon detects an `AMAZON.YesIntent`. This is not what I want! I want the user to follow the flow of the skill I have set out.

Is there a way to govern what intents can be activated at what time? A thought I had was to use attributes to basically set what intents are allowed to be invoked next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [session object](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/request-and-response-json-reference.html#session-object) on each Alexa request.  That session object has a `new` property that is either true or false depending on whether it's a brand new session for your Skill.

If you happen to be using the alexa-sdk node module to build your skill you can also use a `NewSession` handler to catch the new session and divert flow to what ever event/intent you want interaction to begin at. More on the state handlers can be found on the github page [here](https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs#skill-state-management)

Answer (score 1):

While I don't think it is possible to enable/disable intents, you can certain change how they respond. It's easy to use the session object to keep track of what the last intent spoken was. Then your intent handler(s) can read the session object to see what the previous response was in order to choose how to respond.

In your example above, you might save the last question number to the session object. If 'yes' doesn't make sense based on the previous (or lack of) question, then your YesIntent handler could respond with "I'm sorry, I don't know what to do with that", or even maybe just ignore it and start the dialog from the beginning.